# Updating parent node in Binary search tree in JAVA

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am working on Binary search tree and I am having some problems in updating/adding the parent node of current node.Parent node are not getting updated correctly.This is what Iam trying to do:

```
public class binarytree {

    private Node root;

static class Node{

    Node left;
    Node right;
    int value;
    Node parent;

    public Node(Node parent,int value)
        {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
        this.parent = parent;
        }
    }

public void creatBST()
    {
    root = new Node(null,4);
    System.out.println("Binary Search tree with root = "+ root.value);
    insert(root,1);
    insert(root,2);
    insert(root,3);
    insert(root,6);
    insert(root,5);
    insert(root,7);
}

public void insert(Node node, int value)
    {
    Node prevnode = node;
    if(value < node.value)
        {
        if(node.left != null)
            {


            insert(node.left, value);   
            System.out.println("Parent node of node"+ node.left.value+"is:"+prevnode.value);
            }
        else
            {

            node.left = new Node(prevnode,value);
            }
        }
    else if(value > node.value)
        {
        if(node.right != null)
            {
            //prevnode = node;

            insert(node.right, value);
            System.out.println("Parent node of node"+ node.right.value+"is:"+prevnode.value);
            }
        else
            {

            node.right = new Node(prevnode,value);
            }
        }
    }
public static void main(String args [])
    {
    binarytree obj = new binarytree();
    obj.creatBST();
    //obj.printInOrder();
    //obj.check();
    }
}
```

The output which I am getting is:

```
    Binary Search tree with root = 4
Parent node of node1is:4
Parent node of node2is:1
Parent node of node1is:4
Parent node of node6is:4
Parent node of node6is:4
```

which is not the correct output.

Need help me in determining how can I do it correctly.

Comment: I haven't studied this too hard, but it looks like `left` and `right` are the left and right children.  If that's the case, we should always have `node.left.parent==node` and `node.right.parent==node` (for non-null children), correct?  But after `node.right = new Node(prevnode,value);`, then `node.right.parent` is `prevnode`, which seems to violate that invariant.  Again, I haven't tried it or studied it in detail, so maybe that code is OK.  But it looks odd.

Comment: @ajb prevnode is initialised with node everytime insert() is called.So, shouldn't the value of prevnode and node should be same inside insert()?

Comment: It looks like you're right.  Like I said, I didn't study the code in detail.  But having a separate `prevnode` variable, whose only purpose seems to be to hold the same value as `node`, is somewhat confusing.  Is there a reason to have `prevnode` at all?

Comment: I was just trying out to add parent node to each node so that I can do some extra processing like finding the inorder successor. For that i created prevnode variable to denote the parent node of each node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the insertion of nodes is working properly.  The print statements are wrong because they are called after the recursive call to insert the next Node.  For example, after you do insert(root,1) your function works and you have the following structure:

```
          4
         /
        1
```

Now when you call insert(root, 2) you end up at this point in the code:

```
if(node.left != null)
        {


        insert(node.left, value);   
        System.out.println("Parent node of node"+ node.left.value+"is:"+prevnode.value);
        }
```

insert(node.left, value) is called and then the print statement happens.  So while your new tree looks like this:

```
          4
         /
        1
         \
          2
```

The next print statement

```
        System.out.println("Parent node of node"+ node.left.value+"is:"+prevnode.value);
```

will print out node.left.value of 1 and prevnode.value of 4.  You may want to change where your print statements are or write a new method that prints the nodes and parent nodes.

Edit:
I would run this method in your main method to test the tree structure:

```
    public void printParents(Node n){
    if(n.left!= null){
        printParents(n.left);
    }
    if(n.right!=null){
        printParents(n.right);
    }
    if(n.parent != null){
        System.out.println("Parent of " + n.value + " is " + n.parent.value);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("The root node is" + n.value);
    }
}
```

I called it here:

```
public static void main(String args [])
{
binarytree obj = new binarytree();
obj.creatBST();
Node n = obj.root;
obj.printParents(n);
//obj.printInOrder();
//obj.check();
}
```

Comment: I added the print statements to check whether the parent node updation is getting correctly done or not. where should I put them so that I know whether parent node is getting correctly updated or not?

Comment: @user2916886 Check out what I just added. I think that may help you.

Comment: thanks a lot @user3088847! looks like the error was in printing the parent node only and not in adding it.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you might want to fix the insert method:

```
Node currentNode;
public void setCurrentNode(Node node) {
    currentNode = node;
}

public boolean insert(int value) {
    //You should probably insert from an instance variable, not an explicit parameter
    Node n = new Node(currentNode, value);
    if (currentNode.left == null) currentNode.left = n;
    else if (currentNode.right == null) currentNode.right = n;
    else return false;    //If insert failed because currentNode was full
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't think my insert function is working wrong.The nodes are getting inserted correctly as when I am doing any traversal output is coming correct.But the problem is that I am not able to update the parent field correctly which I need for some other processing.

Comment: watch out where your variables are declared and changed.  Don't change your variables in a method if they're the explicit parameters.